# Display R plots running from Python

Tags: python, r, plot, popen

I have the following R script called `Test.R`:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
plot(x,y, type="o")
x
y
```

I am running it via Python using this Python script called `Test.py`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['Path/To/Rscript.exe',
                         'Path/To/Test.R'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print stdout

# Alternative Code to see output
# retcode = subprocess.call(['Path/To/Rscript.exe',
#                            'Path/To/Test.R'])
```

When I run the python script Test.py, I get the following output in Pycharm:

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

So the usual text results show up fine, but how do I get the plots to show?  I've tried changing the file from `Rscript.txt` to `Rgui.exe` but I get the following error and it only opens up Rgui:

```
ARGUMENT Path/To/Test.R __ignored__
```

is there an easy way for the output to display?  I know this is a simple problem but I'm wondering how this will extend to other plot commands in `R` like `acf()` or `pacf()`.  Should I use `ggplot2` to save he plots and just tell Python to open the saved files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
show()
```

after:

```
plot(x,y, type="o")
```

Comment: sorry when I did that I get the following error in stderr:

'Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where) : 
  argument "object" is missing, with no default
Calls: show ... show -> showDefault -> getClass -> .getClassFromCache
Execution halted'

If I use 'show(plot(x,y, type="o"))' the same thing happens.  No output.